# Combine two data fields in highcharts

Tags: highcharts

My char is like that. I want to combine above `On Air Target 2G` and `Actual 2G` as 2G and other two fields `On Ait Target 3G` and `Actual 3G` as 3G.

Before combing it display like this.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9vGQQ.jpg)

After adding new 2G and 3G It should display like that.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G6HLp.jpg)
When I press 2G tha 2G , On Ait Target 2G and Actual 2G should be hidden. and above function....

`$(function () {
        var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
            chart: {
                renderTo: "barchartloadmunthlydatachart",
                type: "column"
            },
            title: {
                style: {
                    'fontSize': '1em'
                },
                useHTML: true,
                x: -27,
                y: 8,
                text: '<span class="chart-title"> Grouped categories <span class="chart-subtitle">plugin by </span></span>'
            },
            plotOptions: {
                column: {
                    stacking: 'normal'
                }
            },
            series: [
                {
                    name: "On Air Target 2G",
                    data: [1, 3, 5, 5, 6, 7, 14, 15, 18],
                    stack: 'target'
                },
                {
                    name: "Actual 2G",
                    data: [3, 5, 10, 15, 16, 18, 18, 18, 19],
                    stack: 'actual'
                },
                {
                    name: "On Air Target 3G",
                    data: [1, 3, 5, 5, 6, 7, 14, 15, 18],
                    stack: 'target'
                },
                {
                    name: "Actual 3G",
                    data: [3, 5, 10, 15, 16, 18, 18, 18, 19],
                    stack: 'actual'
                }
            ],
            xAxis: {
                categories: [{
                        name: "2016-05",
                        categories: ["1st wk", "2nd wk", "3dr wk"]
                    }, {
                        name: "2016-06",
                        categories: ["1st wk", "2nd wk", "3rd wk"]
                    }, {
                        name: "2016-07",
                        categories: ["1st wk", "2nd wk", "3rd wk"]
                    }]
            }
        });
    });`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the two fake series (with unique ID) for printing symbol in the legend and catch [legendItemClick](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.column.events.legendItemClick) event. Inside the function, define the condition which checks G2 / G3 and call series.update() on particular series.

```
events: {
      legendItemClick: function() {
        var chart = this.chart,
          series = chart.series,
          visible;

        if (this.name === '2G') {
          visible = series[0].visible;

          series[0].update({
            visible: !visible
          }, false);

          series[1].update({
            visible: !visible
          }, true);
          return false;
        }

        if (this.name === '3G') {
          visible = series[2].visible;
          series[2].update({
            visible: !visible
          }, false);

          series[3].update({
            visible: !visible
          }, true);
          return false;
        }
      }
    }
```

Example:

- http://jsfiddle.net/o8py1ahc/